# Book recomendations

Tags: galois-theory, book-recommendation, projective-geometry

I am taking a course on Galois Theory and I read that one of its many applications are finite projective planes. I would like to read something regarding this topic.

Are there any 'articles/pdf books/not so expensive books' you recommend me?

It doesn't need to be anything that goes really deep into the topic. I would just like to have some light reading regarding this!

Thank you

Comment: To get an understanding of finite projective planes you only need to know the basics about finite fields. To that end you won't need Galois Theory (even though it is a very fascinating topic). The reason I am making this comment is the following concern: In many texts the finite fields are called *Galois fields*, even denoted $GF(q)$. Many askers thus make the association that Galois Theory is necessary to get to finite fields. Admittedly they are often introduced, along the way, on a course that culminates in an introduction to Galois Theory, but this is by no means necessary.

Comment: For example, if you have a finite field, constructing a finite projective plane is [straight forward](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463369/11619). I really don't want to discourage you from studying Galois Theory, but if your goal is to get to finite projective planes as quickly as possible, then that will not be the fastest route.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you very much for your comment. Is there any book you recommend? When my classes are finished I want to start studying more on this topic but I really do not know what book to start from. Thank you